# How can I manage a remote headless Debian (buster) server with QEMU/KVM Windows 10 install?

Tags: debian, windows, kvm

I have a project computer which I'm going to make headless (the Debian side is headless now, but this Windows-10 KVM needs the GUI for setup and troubleshooting when it goes foo-bar) and deliver to a remote location.

The KVM on this Debian box has one job to do--[forward ODBC calls through a special DLL to other Windows hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647069/help-my-python-script-communicate-from-linux-to-odbc-inside-kvm-windows). The only bits I've installed on the Windows KVM are:

- [Python.org distribution for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/).
- socket server script in Python based on [Real Python's socket programming guide](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/)
- [Non-Sucking Service Manager](https://nssm.cc/) to manage the socket server

So long as this socket server doesn't crash, I'm ok. But, if it does...

**What's the simplest solution where I can have a basic gui view of this KVM from a remote client?**

I looked at this article, but it seems overkill (*"...GPU passthrough and VFIO drivers to achieve near-native performance – for gaming, photo or video editing, and other graphics and CPU intensive tasks."*) and I don't think this dino Dell PowerEdge 110T raid server has 'IOMMU support' (but I could be wrong). [Running Windows 10 on Linux using KVM with VGA Passthrough](https://www.heiko-sieger.info/running-windows-10-on-linux-using-kvm-with-vga-passthrough/#Part_3_-_Determining_the_Devices_to_Pass_Through_to_Windows)

Comment: By "GUI", do you mean you need to be able to access Windows 10? Did you try a remote desktop setup (RDP)? Potentially using port forwarding via `ssh` when you log into the Debian host? (Also, did you try to use Wine to run the "special DLL" directly on Debian?)

Comment: libvirtd which uses qemu as backend + virt-manager (local GUI) makes this easy: you can forward anything over SSH, including the display.